# How to write a linq query to exclude some of the records?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

This is my LINQ

```
IList<string> ExceptList = new List<string>() { "045C388E96", "C9B735E166", "02860EB192", "2401016471" };

                var listusers = context.USER_INFO.Where(x => x.ACTIVATED
                                    && x.COMP.EQUIPMENT.Count(y => y.STATUS == (int)STATUSEQ.ACTIVE) > 0
                                    && (x.LAST_LOGIN < time) 
                                    && !ExceptList.Contains(x.COMP.CODE)
                                    && !x.IS_LOCK
                                    || !x.COMP.IS_LOCK)
                    .Select(x => new EmailOutOfDateLoginModel
                    {
                        COMPCode = x.COMP.CODE,
                        First_Name = x.FIRST_NAME,
                        Last_Name = x.LAST_NAME,
                        Total_EQ = x.COMP.EQUIPMENT.Count(y => y.STATUS == (int)STATUSEQ.ACTIVE),
                        User_Email = x.USER_EMAIL
                    }).ToList();
```

I am not sure why my ExceptList is not working. I want to exclude any record that contaisn any of the CODE in the ExceptList

Comment: 1) Is it Entity Framework query, if yes - which version of EF do you use 2) define "not working" 3) what database the query is run against 4) what query is generated by EF if this is EF

Comment: Is it a casing problem?  Is `x.COMP.CODE` lower case characters?

Comment: Also, shouldn't this part `!x.IS_LOCK || !x.COMP.IS_LOCK` be inside parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your linq all records where (!x.COMP.IS_LOCK==true) will be included in the query. Try this "where" part:

```
.Where(x => x.ACTIVATED
&& x.COMP.EQUIPMENT.Count(y => y.STATUS == (int)STATUSEQ.ACTIVE) > 0
&& (x.LAST_LOGIN < time) 
&& !ExceptList.Contains(x.COMP.CODE) 
&& !(x.IS_LOCK && x.COMP.IS_LOCK))
```

Answer (score 2):

Put parentheses around the expressions containing the && logic. The || at the end is only matched with the !x.IS_LOCK || !x.COMP.IS_LOCK otherwise.